# Netbeans 8.2 not displaying Hermit Font Properly

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts

My favorite programming font is [Hermit](https://pcaro.es/p/hermit/). I have installed this font successfully. In my Sublime Text 3, this font is being displayed properly, but when I set it in Netbeans 8.2 its not displaying properly...it is cutting the lower part of letters like 'P','g',..etc. See below:

[image]

What is wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to install the font from your link on Windows 10, but I managed to get this issue resolved using the variant of **Hermit** font named **Hurmit**.

After installing Hurmit on Windows 10/NetBeans 8.2 the font rendered like this:

[image]

It's still not quite right for 'g' and 'p', but a bit better than yours. However, the rendering is fine when using the [Nightly Development build version of NetBeans](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/):

[image]

This is how I installed **Hurmit**:

- Download **Hurmit Medium Nerd Font Complete Windows Compatible.otf** from https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Hermit/Medium/complete
- Double-click that downloaded OTF file, then click the **Install** button to install the font in **C:\Windows\Fonts**.
- Reboot Windows, then set Hurmit as the default font in NetBeans using **Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors**.

Even if you are using Linux you should still be able to use the non-Windows flavor of Hurmit. Whether you can live with the Dev version of NetBeans is another matter, but it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative, however I have resorted to using Monaco.